# How to detect when a user log in for first time in new system?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication

I want to send a verification code to user, when he/she login first time in a new system.

Example:

1. If user login in desktop 1 for first time, want to redirect to verification page
2. If user login in desktop 2 for first time, want to redirect to verification page

similarly for laptop/mobile or any device when he logs in for first time, I want to redirect him to verification page.

> This feature is similar to google/facebook authentication when he/she
>   login first time in new device.

Suggest better/best way to implement this feature.

Technology stack we are using
**Front end: Angular2, Javascript
Back end/Middle layer: Java**

Comment: You need to have a field on the user in your database in which you can store whether or not the user has logged in before.

Comment: I'd imagine this is something that could be done with cookies. Check if a user has the "first log in cookie", if not redirect to verification otherwise logon.

Comment: Yes agree, but how to generate unique value against user and device? user2085143

Comment: George, How to check "first log in cookie" ? and can I get this from all devices ?

Comment: You generate unique value with random generator on server side and save it. It is not clear what's your expertise in the technologies you've listed and how deep the question should explain the things. The question is too broad any way, it is unlikely that it will get a quality answer. I would suggest to examine how the things work at server side first.